# html-to-image javascript npm package is not showing curved text

Tags: javascript, html, dom, png, anychart

When converting HTML to PNG it is not showing curved text

This has been made using Anycharts [Any Charts](https://www.anychart.com/products/anychart/gallery/Sunburst_Charts/Employee_Count_by_Country.php)

[image]

```
  htmlToImage.toPng(document.getElementById('my-node'))
  .then(function (dataUrl) {
    download(dataUrl, 'my-node.png');
  });
```

But the output does not show curved text.

[image]

On any other chart where the text is not curved, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Problem you have faced may be caused by 3rd party library.
AnyChart provides a solution for downloading your chart in preferable image format.

Use saveAsPng method to [save chart as a png image](https://docs.anychart.com/Common_Settings/Exports#png).

```
//Create a chart instance
var chart = anychart.sunburst(data, "as-tree");

//Set transparent background
chart.background().fill("transparent");

//Download an image
chart.saveAsPng({
      width: 500,
      height: 500,
      quality: 0.3,
      filename: "My Chart PNG",
    });
```

The result image is following:

[image]

You can check out [how to save a cahrt as an image](https://playground.anychart.com/1bqZBIi9/iframe) in a playground